# Azure Data Factory lookup activity error code 2107

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to make a lookup in a csv in Azure Data Factory and I encounter a 2107, I couldn't find the error in MSFT troubleshoot guide.

I test a smaller file and it works. The limit of lookup is 5000 rows, file doesn't exceeds that.

How wide can be a record?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be about your files exceeding the rowcount of 5000, but instead your file might be too big (think of this especially with CSVs)

1. The Lookup activity can return up to 5000 rows; if the result set
   contains more records, the first 5000 rows will be returned.
2. The Lookup activity output supports up to 4 MB in size, activity will fail if the size exceeds the limit.

In this case your file might be over 4 MB in size.

If this does not solve your issue, you can paste the full error message and add more details, I would love to help.

Source: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#supported-capabilities)